# Community 90 Day Edit/Reopen Challenge

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, editing

[The Workplace's question close rate has been oft discussed on meta here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=close+too+much). If you've been around here more than a few minutes, you probably are aware of all the words written on the subject, opinions, and walls of text on the subject.

This isn't going to be one of those. Instead, it's a challenge to us collectively as a community.

**Let's edit/reopen more questions.**

If each of the hundreds of us who have received 1000+ reputation this year edits a single question a week to make it on topic, we can easily make these numbers for the past 90 days([taken from the 10k user tools](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days), boxes mine):

---

[image]

---

Let's collectively make these look different in a positive way. Right now, a reasonably small percentages of closed questions are edited at all (the first column) and often when they do get edited, they don't get reopened.

Even assuming some questions are not redeemable through edits, there are a lot of possible questions.

After 90 days, we can checkin again and see how we're doing (this happens to be January 1st of 2019).

In closing, while there are a ton of meta posts I could link to, I'll link to [jmac's post from years ago](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2220/2322) which is just as relevant now as it was then.

---

## Logistics

If you find yourself making an edit specifically for this purpose, go ahead and add it as an answer below. Once questions are reopened, we can clean up the answers (either you or us as moderators) and keep the list of answers questions currently needing eyes and also make it more obvious when there is an edit associated with this effort.

We can keep the questions (as answers) here until they are non-negative in voting, too, if that applies.

Comment: I'm up for the challenge! :)

Comment: Some further discussion: What should be done to the posts that have negative score? After the edit, I take it that the post will be of higher quality, so should we consider upvoting, so we also take out such posts from the negative zone (as those posts tend to receive few help)?

Comment: @DarkCygnus I added a blurb about that, too, good question!

Comment: Hold my beer... I'm going in!

Comment: [Closed questions that aren't duplicates with no answers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+answers%3A0+duplicate%3Ano) or [if you don't care about whether they have an answer or they're a duplicate](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes)

Answer (score 2):

Mmmmm...no thanks, I won't be participating.

What you're asking me to do is, after a gang of hooligans runs along destroying everything in its path, to run along behind and try to clean up the mess.

I'd really prefer that you stop the hooligans first.

I repeatedly see questions that are [intelligently written](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120550/wife-is-being-sent-out-of-state-for-training-employer-is-not-covering-food-par), that draw [intelligent answers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120483/i-was-assigned-to-a-fake-project-after-being-hired-is-this-bad-news-for-my-care), and that produce [interesting discussion and analysis](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120422/how-do-i-greet-someone-when-bowing-is-the-default-greeting-but-im-unable-to-bow), closed with reasons like "too company-specific" (even though they're not) or "unclear what you're asking" (even though multiple people have found the question clear enough to post answers to it).

I'd much prefer that the moderators deal directly with the **specific people** who make a career of facile question closure.  (It's not hard to go through closed questions and see who they are.)

Ask **them** to be the **first and foremost** to focus their efforts on editing questions and/or posting comments soliciting better detail to reopen the question, rather than just blitzing through closing them.  How about challenging **them** to, say, perform one edit or post one comment (on how to improve a closed question) for every close vote they cast?

Without this, the rest of us are fighting a losing battle.

Comment: In any case, perhaps we should be doing *both* things: stop the "hooligans" and clean what we already have.

Comment: @DarkCygnus That sounds like a good plan.  So tell us, how do we stop the hooligans?

Comment: Ha! If I knew that believe me, I would have already suggested so :)