# (Done) Reopen request: What should I consider when being asked to make a surprising move?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

In the spirit of [Community 90 Day Edit/Reopen Challenge](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5603/2322) I picked a closed question over the past week and made an edit:

- [What should I consider when being asked to make a surprising move?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120038/what-should-i-consider-when-being-asked-to-make-a-surprising-move)

I removed the "tell me what to do" and focused more on the general problem. I think the general question here is definitely answerable and a good one I don't recall having seen here before.

Comment: Nicely done.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update:* The post was reopened.

---

I see the edit, and think it is on point. Now the post is IMO on-topic and answerable.

Casted the 2nd vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Nice one, have cast my reopen vote.

Answer (score -1):

I am glad that question was re-opened.

It is sad that some folks think that such a trite change in phrasing turns a question from being "unanswerable/off-topic/bad-question" to "answerable/on-topic/good-question".

The entire essence of the change was merely "**should I**" ==> "**what should I consider**"

Come on, seriously?

If the question had been left-as-is and not closed, it is still a good question (and in my opinion, **THE SAME QUESTION**). Any good answer would, of course, go into detail about one "what things to consider" and may or may not take a "yes or no" approach to the "should I?" aspect.

Comment: `Any good answer would, of course, go into detail about one "what things to consider" and may or may not take a "yes or no" approach to the "should I?" aspect` As much as I agree with this in theory, my 5+ years of experience here reflects a different reality than the theory in how people answer these types of questions.

Comment: It's not likely that this edit changed anyone's mind. The folks who always like to close questions quickly almost certainly aren't the ones who voted to re-open the question. The game seems to go like this, over and over again: 1) A question is posted 2) A small group of folks rush in to be the first to vote to close 3) The question is put on hold 4) An appeal is made in Meta to re-open the question 5) Other folks vote to re-open.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, Exactly, such re-phrasing serves no real purpose other to appease the persnickety-ness of VTC-cops. Seems like a lot of labor to workaround the impulsive decisions of VTC-ers.

Comment: @teego1967 - I think the rephrasing makes the question better, so it does indeed have a purpose. My point was that rephrasing doesn't change the mind of most of those who originally voted to close. In virtually all cases, a different group of people vote to reopen. I'm not saying I like it, I'm just trying to express what is actually happening, IMHO.

Comment: @ElysianFields, Well, if someone had just answered "yes" or "no" to the original question that answer would have been downvoted simply because it would have been too short and doesn't go into detail. What I am saying is that it would have been perfectly fine to have left the question as-is.